# SSRS 2008 R2 Reports in IE11 (Native)

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2008-r2

My team is currently working on some work to make our web application work with IE11.  There have been a plethora of problems that we've worked through, but the most unknown problem at this point is that none of our SQL Server Reports render any data when viewed in IE11 (native).  I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 and am handcuffed to this version currently.

In our app (ASP.NET web app), we have an aspx page that has a ReportViewer control (version 9.0.0.0) added to it that renders the reports.  I can change the Document Mode to 7 from Edge and the data begins to show up, but I'm looking for a more permanent, programmatic solution to this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We've had to temporarily switch to Compatibility View. In our case, we have a horizontal line in the page footer. If we remove that line and not use Compatibility View the report works. I'm currently checking, but, I think the line is an ActiveX control and that could be causing the issue.